# Clear canvas context without knowing the canvas dimensions

Tags: html5-canvas

To clear a canvas to transparency, you do this:

```
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.clearRect(0,0,  //Starting coordinates
           canvas.width, canvas.height //Ending coordinates
);
```

But I'm writing a more complex abstract system. To avoid calling `.getContext` all over the place, I have a pseudo-class to manage contexts of all layers. Every sub-program is then passed a `ctx` variable without the canvas:

```
Something.prototype.renderMe = function(ctx) {
    //draw Something
}
```

I occurred to need to clear all context area. Is that possible just with canvas context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The context contains a property which refers to its canvas.

```
var myCanvas=ctx.canvas;
ctx.clearRect(0,0,myCanvas.width,myCanvas.height);
```